# How to transform this specific js array into js object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have one javascript array got from back end api, for convenience, need to be sort into the form of below, described as final target.

But I don't know how to start. Anyone can help?

The original src array is like below :

```js
var src = [
  {
    "parent_kind" : "Animal",
    "name" : "Cow"
  },
  {
    "name" : "Animal"
  },
  {
    "parent_kind" : "Animal",
    "name" : "Dog"
  },
  {
    "parent_kind" : "Animal",
    "name" : "Horse"
  },
  {
    "name" : "Vehicle"
  },
  {
    "parent_kind" : "Vehicle",
    "name" : "Bus"
  },
  {
    "parent_kind" : "Bus",
    "name" : "Shuttle"
  },
]
```

The final target is :

```json
{
  "Vehicle" : {
    "Bus" : {
      "Shuttle" : {}
    }
  },
  "Animal" : {
    "Cow" : {},
    "Dog" : {},
    "Horse" : {}
  }
}
```

I can got each element of the original array by

```js
for (let ele of src) {
  console.log(ele)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that with a simple Array.reduce() method

```js
var src = 
  [ { parent_kind: 'Animal',  name: 'Cow'     } 
  , {                         name: 'Animal'  } 
  , { parent_kind: 'Animal',  name: 'Dog'     } 
  , { parent_kind: 'Animal',  name: 'Horse'   } 
  , {                         name: 'Vehicle' } 
  , { parent_kind: 'Vehicle', name: 'Bus'     } 
  , { parent_kind: 'Bus',     name: 'Shuttle' } 
  ] 

let res = src.reduce((a,{parent_kind,name},i)=>
  {
  if(!!parent_kind) 
    {
    let np = a.p.find(x=>x.pN===parent_kind)
    if(!np)
      {
      a.r[parent_kind] = {}
      np = {pN:parent_kind, e:a.r[parent_kind]} 
      a.p.push( np )
      }
    let z = np.e[name] = {}
    a.p.push( {pN:name, e:z} )
    }
  return (i===a.len)? a.r : a    
  }
  ,{len:src.length-1,r:{},p:[]})

console.log( res )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can ok with loop the src many times :-( That's performance is not a concern.

```js
var src = [{
    "parent_kind": "Animal",
    "name": "Cow"
  },
  {
    "name": "Animal"
  },
  {
    "parent_kind": "Animal",
    "name": "Dog"
  },
  {
    "parent_kind": "Animal",
    "name": "Horse"
  },
  {
    "name": "Vehicle"
  },
  {
    "parent_kind": "Vehicle",
    "name": "Bus"
  },
  {
    "parent_kind": "Bus",
    "name": "Shuttle"
  },
];

const fn = (source, result, parent) => {
  const children = source.filter(({
    parent_kind
  }) => parent_kind === parent).map(({
    name
  }) => name);
  children.forEach(c => result[c] = {});
  children.forEach(c => fn(source, result[c], c));
}

result = {};
fn(src, result)
console.log(result);
```